# Using Crypt::RSA for data signing in perl

Tags: perl, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to sign my data before sending it over HTTPS connection to server. Problem i am encountering is that when i read my private key from id_rsa it gives error. My code is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::RSA;

my $rsa = new Crypt::RSA ( ES => 'PKCS1v15' );
my $pkey  = new Crypt::RSA::Key::Private ( Filename => '/home/abc/.ssh/id_rsa' );

print $pkey;
```

On printing it is giving errors like `Bareword found where operator expected` and `Number found where operator expected`.

I am not able to understand what might be the issue.

The error message start in this way `Number found where operator expected at (eval 21) line 6, near "ZapzlA9gZ8
23"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 21) line 6, near "23mqj2RsKOF0Lal7YbjYFkDE7YrLPktf0FNNYvn6BjKZDlyQfpWnk8dP3crjoown"
    (Missing operator before mqj2RsKOF0Lal7YbjYFkDE7YrLPktf0FNNYvn6BjKZDlyQfpWnk8dP3crjoown?)
Number found where operator expected at (eval 21) line 9, near "QUgHQAJ4R
34"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 21) line 9, near "34Csy0lcx"
    (Missing operator before Csy0lcx?)
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at (eval 21) line 10.`

There are lot of lines like those above and after that in the last line the message is

`Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at Number found where operator expected at 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Crypt/RSA/Key/Private.pm line 217.`

Comment: There is usually a line number and package name associated with error message. Please show all necessary information.

Comment: I have provided that line number and package name associated with the error. Thanks

Comment: An SSH private key file isn't a Crypt::RSA private key file, even if it happens to use the RSA SSH key format.

Comment: So how can i use SSH private key file for signing. I looked into `Crypt::RSA::Key::Private::SSH` but i am not able to use it. I was hoping that it might be able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest trying Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA if you can.

Comment: I tried using Crypt::OpenSSl::RSA but it is giving error `RSA.xs:178: OpenSSL error: unsupported encryption at test.pl line 20`. My line 20 is `my $privatekey = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($keystring);`